# Can I upload to Spaces using a signed url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, digital-ocean

Im currently developing a React webapp that lets users upload images. I have it working with AWS S3 but would like to have everything on DO for simplicities sake.

The flow goes like this:

Send image info to server and receive a signed url
Post the image to the signed url

When i try this with spaces im constantly getting a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error.

Please help, im going batty!

My node server generating the signed url:

```
spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint(`${DO_REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com`),
s3 = new aws.S3({
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    accessKeyId: DO_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: DO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: DO_REGION,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

const s3Params = {
    Bucket: DO_SPACE,
    Expires: 60,
    Key: filePath,
    ContentType: fileType, // "image/jpeg"
    ACL: 'public-read',
};

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, url) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(url);
    });
});
```

my client side js posting after retrieving the signed url

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open('PUT', payload.signedUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Host', `${DO_SPACE}.${DO_REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com');
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', payload.file.type);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', payload.file.size);
xhr.send(payload.file);
```